# Establish a drupal session when I login in react and redux

Tags: reactjs, drupal, session-cookies, headless

I need to establish a session when I login, when I put username and password Drupal sends me a response with the csrf-token.  However, I don't know how to create the session in react?

```
export const auth = (username, password) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(authStart())
        const authData= {
            name: username,
            pass: password
        }
         axios.post('http://localhost:8000/user/login?_format=json', authData)
            .then(response => {
                    localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.csrf_token);
                    localStorage.setItem('fullName', response.data.current_user.name);
                    localStorage.setItem('logoutToken', response.data.logout_token)
                    /* dispatch(authSuccess(response.data.csrf_token, response.data.current_user.name))   */
                                    
            })
         axios.get('http://localhost:8000/session/token')
        .then(res => {
            axios.create({
                baseURL: "http://localhost:8000",
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': res.data
                }
            })
            dispatch(authSuccess(res.data, "test"))
        }) 
    };
};
```

Comment: You don't start any session in react, you would add the token when sending post requests. Maybe [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/235141/headless-drupal-8-cookie-authentication) or [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263328/approach-to-create-headless-drupal-with-login) answers your question.

Comment: yes, I got a bit confused, so I am gonna check your suggests.  Thanks.